# Invalid syntax on arcpy.conversion.FeatureClasstoFeatureClass()

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, feature-class, syntaxerror

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.1.

In a Python script tool, I am trying to get a list of feature classes as an user supplied input parameter, and export all of them with an additional text string that is also a user supplied input parameter. Here is my code,

```
import arcpy

fcList = arcpy.GetParameter(0) #input features
outFC_Dir = arcpy.GetParameter(1) #output geodatabase
desc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  #text to append onto input layer name, intended to be project name and date                                  
                                    
proj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')

for fc in fcList: #attempting to iterate through all the input features and extract their names as text
    f_name = ' '.join(map(str(fc)
    f_name = (f_name + desc)
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fcList, outFC_Dir, f_name)
```

This is my error messsage

```
line 11
    f_name = (f_name + desc)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I had more lines of code commented out, and

```
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fcList, outFC_Dir, f_name)
```

was on line 17, I would get the error

```
line 17
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fcList, outFC_Dir, f_name)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can't figure out what is causing this syntax error. I am completely open to better ways of accomplishing my task of converting the input layers names to text, appending them to more text, and exporting all of them.

Comment: You're missing 2 closing parentheses on the previous line. `f_name = ' '.join(map(str(fc)))` will fix the syntax error, but probably still won't work as you're using `' '.join(etc)` to insert a space between every character of each layer name.

Comment: Whenever the Python parser generates an error on a line that seems fine, it is usually  a missing paren in the statement(s) above.

Answer (score 1):

The below will take either shapefile or feature class (or a mixture of), and convert to feature class in defined gdb, adding the additional naming to the end as per user input. Code commented.

```
import arcpy

## input features
fcList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
## output geodatabase
outFC_Dir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
## text to append onto input layer name, intended to be project name and date
desc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

## removes the formatting of the text and puts the feature classes
## into a list
fcList = fcList.replace("'", "").split(";")

for fc in fcList:
    ## get the fc name, if a shapefile the .shp will still be present
    fc_name = fc.rsplit("\\", 1)[1]

    ## if its a shapefile, remove .shp and make sure no spaces
    if fc_name.endswith(".shp"):
        fc_name = fc_name.replace(" ", "_")[:-4]

    ## you might want to place validation on th decription input to make sure
    ## that is doesnt contain and spaces or special characters as per fc standard
    fc_name = "{0}_{1}".format(fc_name, desc)

    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, outFC_Dir, fc_name)
```